# in Emacs, how to instruct Flyspell to permit certain repeated words?

Tags: emacs, flyspell

In Emacs, I use Flyspell to check my spelling. By default, Flyspell highlights repeated words.

But certain words are intentionally repeated, e.g. "ha ha." How can I instruct Flyspell to permit certain words to be repeated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
flyspell-mark-duplications-exceptions is a variable defined in `flyspell.el'.
Its value is ((nil "that" "had") ("\\`francais" "nous" "vous"))

Documentation:
A list of exceptions for duplicated words.
It should be a list of (LANGUAGE . EXCEPTION-LIST).

LANGUAGE is nil, which means the exceptions apply regardless of
the current dictionary, or a regular expression matching the
dictionary name (`ispell-local-dictionary' or
`ispell-dictionary') for which the exceptions should apply.

EXCEPTION-LIST is a list of strings.  The checked word is
downcased before comparing with these exceptions.

You can customize this variable.

This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
version 24.1 of Emacs.
```